# How do I compare two dates in Sharepoint listview with javascript?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I want to compare two dates in a sharepoint list using javascript.
2 years ago I asked a question about comparing two dates in sharepoint. The code I use is this:

```
var date = new Date(listItem.LTIOV);
var todaysDate = new Date();

if ((date < todaysDate) && (listItem.MijnStatus == "In Action")) {
    if (row != null){
        row.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(153, 204, 255, 0.5)"; //light blue
    }
}
```

Back then is worked because the date in listitem.LTIOV was only a date and no time. This time my date also has a time part in it. I already tried with date.GetTime() but the results are not correct. Some dates come back with a year in the future like 2022.

Anyone know how to do this?

Marco

Answer (score 0):

The `new Date(listItem.LTIOV)` would also get the time, if you don't have time in listitem.LTIOV, it would return as in 00:00:00 for the time.

So, you could compare two dates with time like this:

```
var date = new Date(date1);
var date = new Date(date2);
if(date1<date2){

}
```

Reference:

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

Comment: I think i am already doing that if you look at my code. Still the list item LTIOV date comes back wrong

Comment: I tried the code that Michael Han suggested, like following: 

`var itemDate = new Date(listItem.DueDate);
var todaysDate = new Date();
if ((itemDate < todaysDate) && (listItem.Status == "Active"))
 { if (row != null) row.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(252, 213, 192, 0.5)"; //light orange
} } `

Here are the dates coming back: 
Wed Sep 8 08:30:00 UTC+0200 2021 - 21-8-2020 08:30 
Wed Dec 8 08:00:00 UTC+0100 2021 - 24-8-2020 08:00 
Thu Jul 7 08:00:00 UTC+0200 2022 - 31-7-2020 08:00

could it be my code needs the $( document ).ready() to get the right dates?